# i got this exception java.sql.SQLException: 404 OK when i run my appengine app on local

Tags: java, google-app-engine

[image]

how can i fix this exception i can't get acces to the database on cloud google with app engine plug-in

im using the appengine 1.9.22

this is my print stack:
juin 11, 2016 7:41:30 PM

```
com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsServiceRemoteDriver openConnection
AVERTISSEMENT: openConnection
java.sql.SQLException: 404 OK
Not Found
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi.newOpenConnectionIOException(RpcGoogleApi.java:168)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi.openConnection(RpcGoogleApi.java:102)
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsServiceRemoteDriver.openConnection(LocalRdbmsServiceRemoteDriver.java:206)
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsService.openConnection(LocalRdbmsService.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:475)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:493)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:490)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 404 OK
Not Found
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1061)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi$DefaultGoogleApi.execImpl(RpcGoogleApi.java:326)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi$DefaultGoogleApi.exec(RpcGoogleApi.java:308)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi.openConnection(RpcGoogleApi.java:99)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/ says "To test in your development environment, you need to connect to a local MySQL server" - did you set one up?

Comment: yes i did, but it can't connect

Comment: it displayed: could not connect to profile (webapp.ggogleCloudSQL.DevInstance). (Error.:404 Not Founf Not Found) 404 Not Found Not Found Error creating  Google Cloud Sql coonection factory connection to profile (webapp.GoogleSQL.DevInstance). (Error: 404 Not Found

Comment: Check the  address you've configured for local access. I can only guess that it's somehow not the right one. The stacktrace does not contain any further information.

Comment: it was work fine, i don't change anything about the database adresse, this probleme appear recently with all my projects with different version of appengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using the second generation of cloud sql to connect to my db when i run on local :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last Friday.

I didn't found any documentation to support this claim but, by reading [current google's documentation and guides on how to connect to cloud sql with java](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-createapp#create), it appears that rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsServiceRemoteDriver is deprecated.

I would recommend you to upgrade your code to use com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver in production and MySQL Connector/J in development.

In development, you could use your own mysql database running on localhost or remotely. If you want to use a db from Google Cloud SQL you could configure your instance of cloud SQL to [allow external access](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external) from your network and then create a connection like any other mysql server.

You could create create a db connection for each runtime environment:

```
    protected Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{

        Connection c = null;
        String url = null;
        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {    
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Driver unavailable.");
            }

            url = System.getProperty("ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url.prod");
        }else{
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Driver unavailable.");
            }

            url = System.getProperty("ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url.dev");
        }

        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        c.setAutoCommit(false);

        return c;
    }
```

Extracted from the documentation:

-[Creating a New Web App with Cloud SQL Support](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-createapp)

-[Using Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-createapp)